# Github: How can I notify to slack when specific branch is merged into master?

Tags: git, github, slack

I have 3 branches

- develop
- master
- feature

Branch of PR is feature and it gonna be merged into master. However, all branches should be merged into develop before merged into master. But, I forgot this action many times. Therefore, I want notification of Slack before a specific branch is merged into master.

How can I implement this? I searched for Github actions or Slack app, but couldn't find.

Answer (score 7):

It was late, But the answer might help someone else

```
/github subscribe owner/repo commits:master
```

You can mention any branch name in the place of master

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own GitHub action to notify you in Slack when a pull request is created and display the base ref/branch. That way you can see which branch you will be merging into.

Here is a helpful article for creating a custom GitHub action for Slack notifications for pull requests:
https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-use-github-actions-to-automate-tests-and-slack-notifications/

Here is the data you can get from the github.event.pull_request object:
https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#pull_request

Answer (score 0):

You can add github to your slack workspace to get updates on different things: https://slack.github.com/

In your channel you go `/github subscribe [yourRepo]` to activate updates.

Comment: I know that app, but it notifies all the activities. I want notification only for merging into master

Comment: You could subscribe to only pulls with `/github subscribe [repo] Pulls`, but I'm not actually sure how to limit that to certain branches.

Comment: Then, can I customize message for notification? For example, "Pull request is merged, be careful for deployment!"

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You'll have to use ThaiGQ's solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/github subscribe owner/repo commits:all
```

This will subscribe to all the branches